# Best way to practice Bash command line in Windows? (Bash\Linux\Noob)

Tags: linux, windows, bash, command-line, wsl-2

I'm learning command line fundamentals for data science, working independently. The book I'm studying has various exercises using a Bash shell. It includes a set of practice files and folders for each chapter. I have a windows machine, with the latest version of Windows 10 Pro. My questions are:

1.) What's the best way to run a bash shell on my machine? (I think the answer is WSL2, but I'm not sure.)

2.) What Linux distribution would be best? (I think the answer is Ubuntu, but I'm not sure.)

3.) Can I just put the practice files and folders anywhere in my Windows file system? (No idea.)

Thanks!

Comment: This question is off-topic accordingly to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic > Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: This question is not suitable for Stack Overflow as it is opinions based - "best" is subjective. Personally I would use a VM such as Virtual Box and then install Ubuntu. But that's only one way and there are other effective paths. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run bash script in windows, I just install git for windows, and it brings bash and most popular gnu tools. But any bash on windows will works slower, than native.
So my proposition - install any virtual machine (virtualbox, vmware) and install ubuntu or other linux on it.

For practice - just look "bash" tag on stackoverflow, finding question related to writing scripts or commands to parse/work with data in bash and try to write your solution

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the best option is installing GNU/Linux distro on your machine(I recommend any Debian-based distro) or at lease having it as a virtual machine, but if you want to run bash shell on Windows 10 machine [here](https://itsfoss.com/install-bash-on-windows/) are 2 ways to do it